# How to create a loop with recurring pow in Python?

Tags: python, math, pow

I don't know almost anything about programming, so my code is probably very bad.

I need the program to take the number I input (n), do n^n-1, then take n+1 and do (n+1)^(n^n-1), then n+2 and do (n+2)^(n+1)^(n^n-1)... etc. This is repeated y times.
Now the easy way is to just do

```
pow(n+1,pow(n,n-1))
pow(n+2,pow(n+1,pow(n,n-1)))
pow(n+3,pow(n+2,pow(n+1,pow(n,n-1))))
pow(n+4,pow(n+3,pow(n+2,pow(n+1,pow(n,n-1)))))
pow(n+5,pow(n+4,pow(n+3,pow(n+2,pow(n+1,pow(n,n-1))))))
```

...and so on

But that's way too ugly and long, especially for longer sequences. So I came up with the code below and started testing it for n=1. It does the math fine up until 4, but then at 5 something breaks and it returns an incorrect value (which at this point should be 5^262144). I don't understand how to fix that and if there even is such a `for loop` that will make this work. [yes I know that even I manage to write the correct code there's not enough ram in the world to compute the next number in this sequence, but I'm not planning to run this, I just want to create code that'll work in theory, on a computer with infinite memory and processing power]

```
import math

print("Please input an integer greater than or equal to 1:")
n = int(input())
x = str(n-1)
r = str(n)+x
y = int(r)
print("Sequence starts:")
print(pow(n,n-1))
for n in range(n, y+1):
    print (pow(n+1,pow(n,n-1)))
```

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated!

Comment: To imagine how to solve this, assign the first value to a variable `a = pow(n+1,pow(n,n-1))` and think how you can replace part of the second line by `a`. Then assign second line to `b` and try to shorten third line in the same way and so on. You should see a pattern then.

Comment: Are you saying the value of a number should be 5^262144? That is an *insanely* large number, you probably wont be able to create a variable that will store even a meaningful approximation of something that large very easily

Answer (score 0):

*I am not quite sure* if I understand what you are looking for, but have a look at this code.

```
import math

def rn(n):
    if (n == 1):
        return 1
    else:
        return pow(n+1, pow(n, n-1))


print(rn(5))
```

Comment: (1) Your code doesn't contain a recursion. (2) I guess that the poster wants a less advanced solution without recursion.

Comment: just realised is not actual recursion, you are right. edited the answer, thank you